# Adding elements from a 1D vector to a 2D vector

Tags: c, loops, vector

I have a 1D vector named geoData and then I have a 2D vector called redVec with user defined rows and columns. I want to add the elements from the 1D vector into the 2D vector but I get a bad access error in xCode.

```
for(int r = 0; r < numRows; ++r){
    for(int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c){
        for(int i = 0; i < geoData.size(); ++i){
            redVec[r][c] = geoData.at(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you initialize your redVec and each inner vector(!) with proper sizes? Secondly, your innermost loops does strange thing. You probably want something like

```cpp
for(int i = 0, r = 0; r < numRows; ++r){
    for(int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c){ 
        redVec[r][c] = geoData.at(i);
        i++; // increase i each time new cell is filled
    }
}
```

or even if you don't created vectors of required sizes beforehand

```cpp
for(int i = 0, r = 0; r < numRows; ++r){
    vector<whatever_type_you_have> row = vector...
    for(int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c){ 
        row.push_back(geoData.at(i))
        i++; // increase i each time new cell is filled
    }
    redVec.push_back(row)
}
```